# How do I manually enter characters in a char[ ] array?

Tags: c++

Suppose I declare an array

> *char name[20];*

and I have to enter the name "Andrew"*(less than 20 characters)* in the variable manually, how is it possible?

**Edit : I tried this code and it is giving me this error

> error: incompatible types in assignment of const char[10] to char[30]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    float percentage;
};
int main()
{
    int i;
    student record1;
    student record2;
    record1.id=1;
    record1.name = "Sir Simon";
    record2.id=2;
    record2.name = "de Canterville";
    puts(record1.name);
    puts(record2.name);
}
```

Comment: You could assign the characters one by one to successive elements of the array [or call strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

Comment: Enter by user or just store with code?

Comment: name[0]='A'; name[1]='n'; ...

Comment: @ItayB enter by user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, since, with an array, you can access individual array elements via `[x]` (where `x` is the element you wish to access).

In these examples, I'm assuming that "Andrew" is a C string (i.e. it ends with a null character).

The first way (the most tedious one) would be to set each array element individually:

```
name[0] = 'A';
name[1] = 'n';
name[2] = 'd';
name[3] = 'r';
name[4] = 'e';
name[5] = 'w';
name[6] = 0; /* If this is not a C string, and you literally want the characters "Andrew" (and only these characters), you can skip this line) */
```

But, this is obviously a bit of a pain to type. Thankfully, C has a neat feature where you can initialize an array in one line, without needing to have a separate statement for each element:

```
char name[20] = {'A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', 0};
```

But there's an easier way too! If you use double quotes (`"..."`), it will basically equate the code above (with the fancy `{...}` notation):

```
char name[20] = "Andrew"; // This adds the NULL (0) character at the end
```

The last two methods (although not the first, the first can be run whenever) I presented, however, can only be run during initialization of the variable, and cannot be run later. In other words, you cannot do this:

```
char name[20];
name = "Andrew";
```

In this case, we can either use the first method (very tedious!!) or we can use a neat function included in `<string.h>`, called `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(name, "Andrew");
```

`strcpy` works by copying the source (`"Andrew"`) to the destination (`name`) until it meets the NULL character (and will copy the NULL character too). This function is also useful when you don't have a constant value. For example, you can do this:

```
char* my_home[20];
char* home_directory = getenv("HOME"); /* an example of a non-constant value */
strcpy(my_home, home_directory);
```

However, this can be really unsafe if the length of the string you're copying is larger than the size of the destination array. For this, use `strncpy`, which will copy until either the NULL character is reached, or the maximum amount of characters you specify have been copied:

```
strncpy(name, "Andrew", 20);
```

Notice that if the source (`"Andrew"`) is longer than 20, no NULL character will be added. So if you want to keep it a C string, try this instead:

```
strncpy(name, "Andrew", 19);
name[19] = 0;
```

---

EDIT: As to why it's impossible to do `char name[20]; name = "Andrew";`, I'm not aware of any technical reason that makes it impossible to do this. I'm guessing this is just a limitation in C's syntax.

I decided to see what happens in assembly, so, from this source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char text[] = "Hello World!";

    puts(text);

    return 0;
}
```

The assembly output was:

```
...
movabsq $8022916924116329800, %rax  ; Sets %rax to "Hello Wo"
movq    %rax,             -16(%rbp) ; Moves %rax to text[0-7]
movl    $560229490,        -8(%rbp) ; Sets text[8-11] to "rld!"
movb    $0,                -4(%rbp) ; text[12] = 0;
...
```

This could be done, in theory, at any point in time, not just at initialization. So, as to why C doesn't allow this, I have no idea. For now, you just have to settle for using `strcpy`, or, if you wish to follow what the assembly does:

```
*((uint64_t*)text)       = 8022916924116329800;
*(((uint32_t*)text) + 2) = 560229490;
text[12]                 = 0;
```

Don't do this unless you want to seriously annoy your coworkers though :P I'm pretty sure most modern compilers should optimize away the `strcpy` function if it's a constant (i.e. `"Andrew"` instead of a variable or function, like `getenv("HOME")`).

Comment: @user3500780 Updated my answer! Try replacing `record1.name = "Sir Simon";` with `strcpy(record1.name, "Sir Simon");` (you'll have to `#include <string.h>` to do this)

Comment: Yep, it does work now :) Any idea why this the only way to do in structures rather than just equating?

Comment: I'm afraid all I can tell you is "because that's how it is" :( I checked the assembly output, and, in theory, it's entirely possible to do this (it copies the text to the stack, which could be done at any point in time), so I'm guessing this is just a limitation in C's syntax? I'm sorry I can't help more, I wish I knew the real answer myself!

Answer (score 2):

You are specify the c++ language and array of char and ask to enter value manually. The answer is:

```
char name[20] = "Andrew";
```

If you mean to read value from console, use this:

```
cin.get(name, 20);
```

But better use c++ library:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string name;
std::cin >> name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either this way:

```
char name[20] = "Andrew";
```

Or, without the syntactic sugar:

```
char name[20] = {'A','n','d','r','e','w','\0'};
```

Comment: Remember that C strings end with a NULL character :)

Comment: @MiJyn In this case, name[6] is null character?

Comment: No, the NULL character is `0` (or `'\0'` if you wish to use quotes). This is so that functions know when the string ends (it's standard convention in C) :) (I was referring to the second example they gave, the first example is fine)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
`strcpy(name, "Some Name")`

Comment: This is already included with proper explanation in the accepted answer.

Comment: but I am not aware of how many people will give the answer(s) after my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of the timing. In any case: When giving an answer, please make sure to include an explanation, not just a code snippet.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. I try to follow ur suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the first answer, try this code and it will show how this assignment works on the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char name[20] = "Andrew";
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ": " << name[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The characters in "Andrew" are assigned to name and the rest of the elements of the fixed size array are empty.